# Does Autodesk Forge maintain a copy of the data files if user delete a files?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management

We have an application which uses Autodesk Forge Model Derivative for showing Revit files.
We are wondering what happens when we delete the data files. Are they deleted permanently or Forge keeps a backup copy? Also, it would be great if someone can add a link of Forge Data privacy policy.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rest assured that Autodesk Forge strictly adheres to GDPR

> (The EU GDPR (European Union - General Data Protection Regulation) is a regulation in the EU which seeks to harmonize and simplify a patchwork of existing data regulations and laws across the EU)

And that we are committed to our security policy that data we and our customers generate is powerful and with great power comes great responsibility. As Autodesk collects, processes, and utilizes data, we have a great responsibility to secure and protect it. Our customers expect it, and laws require it.

See more details [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/eu-general-data-protection-regulation-extension-existing-autodesk-policies) and [here](https://www.autodesk.com/trust/compliance)